# Solr Search: exact and "only" search in TokenizerChain (solr6)

Tags: search, solr

I have a field "brand" its defined as Field-Type: "org.apache.solr.schema.TextField" and Index-Analyzer and Query-Analyzer: "org.apache.solr.analysis.TokenizerChain".

I wanna search for one text and only this text. E. g. search for "Lego" brings also the results for "Lego", "Lego Mio", "Lego Plus" and "Lego Plus Sub". But i just wanna have the results for "Lego". Same when i search for "Lego Plus" i find "Lego Plus Sub" too, but just wanna have "Lego Plus".

I tried this with some regex expressions, but its not wirking.

Do you have some ideas?

thx in advance :)

best rudolf

Answer (score 0):

You can either use a StrField - which will only give you a result if there's an exact match, or you can use a TextField with a KeywordTokenizer. The KeywordTokenizer will keep the input string as a single token, in effect only matching if there's an exact match.

The difference is that you can apply filters to the result from the KeywordTokenizer, such as a LowerCaseFilter, enabling you to match regardless of case.